# can antifreeze concentrate or get stronger in a vehicle with out loss of fluid level?

Tags: coolant

My wife recently went to get the oil changed in our 2012 Subaru Outback, when she went to pick it up the clerk recommended a radiator flush and refill as the coolant level tested at -65 degree's. Is this even possible with out a loss of fluid in the system? (water)
I too talked with the service rep who told me the same thing and thought that the fires in the area might have something to do with it. ???
I think this is just an up sell and decline any further service.

Comment: I think that you have it nailed.

Comment: If it's a 2012 you probably would benefit from a coolant flush. Not allowing the fluid to chemically deteriorate helps the rubber hoses last longer as well as keeps the inside of the engine clean. Coolant flushes are fairly easy to do yourself following even generic guides on youtube.

Comment: +1 on finleyarcher's comment, if this is some quick LOF place that recommended the "flush" don't waste your money and do it yourself.

Comment: @NumairAidroos - How is that pertinent to the conversation?

Comment: @paul, I believe this is, more of a suspicion, of sale vs requirement, query.